# I am not able to fetch and delete data from Sq-lite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created database to perform add to cart functioning.
This is my database helper class.

```js
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "soulcluster";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCT = "product";

    private static final String TABLE_ADD_TO_CART = "addtocart";

    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_NAME = "productname";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE = "productprice";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = "productdescription";


public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

        String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_PRODUCT + "("
                + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE + " BLOB NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";

        String CREATE_ADD_TO_CART_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
                + TABLE_ADD_TO_CART + "("
                + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE + " BLOB NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ADD_TO_CART_TABLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created" + CREATE_USER_TABLE + " " + CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE + " " + CREATE_ADD_TO_CART_TABLE);
    }
public void addToCart(String product_id, byte [] image, String productName, String productPrice, String productDescription){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID, product_id);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE, image);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE, productPrice);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, productDescription);

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_ADD_TO_CART, null, contentValues);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "New product added into Add to cart " + product_id + " " + image + " " + productName + " " + productPrice + " " + productDescription + " " +id);
    }

    public void deleteAddToCartItem(String id){
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "delete from " + TABLE_ADD_TO_CART + " where id=\'" + id + "'";
            Log.d("", "Id is here " + id);
            db.execSQL(query);
            db.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("", " Something is wrong");
        }

    }
public ArrayList<AddToCartItems> fetchProduct()
    {
        ArrayList<AddToCartItems> product = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String query = "select * from " + TABLE_ADD_TO_CART  ;
        Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do{
                AddToCartItems addToCartItems = new AddToCartItems();
                addToCartItems.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                addToCartItems.setImageArray(cursor.getBlob(1));
                addToCartItems.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                addToCartItems.setPrice(cursor.getString(3));
                addToCartItems.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));

                product.add(addToCartItems);
                Log.d("", "check -----" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("productname")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                cursor.moveToNext();
                Log.d("", "Inside fetching method" + " " + cursor.getCount() + " " + product.size() );
                System.out.print(cursor.getCount());
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());


        /*    for (int a = 0; a < cursor.getCount(); a++){

            }*/
        }
        Log.d("", "Checkimh product size " + product.size());
        db.close();
        return product;
    }
```

I have just posted required methods.
In my adapter class on click of add to cart bucket the product will added into database.

```js
holder.add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), items.getItem_Image());
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();

                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
                String productID = sm.format(d);

                db.addToCart(productID, bitmapdata, items.getItem_name(), items.getItem_price(), items.getDescription());
                //AppController.getInstance().addToCartItemses(items.getItem_Image(), items.getItem_name(), items.getItem_price(), items.getDescription());
                Log.d(""," ShopAdapter " + " " + bitmapdata + " " + productID + " " + items.getItem_Image() + " "+ items.getItem_name()+ " "+ items.getItem_price() +" " +items.getDescription());
            }
        });
```

here is that method. I have used image as button and on clicking that image insert query fires.

This is the delete method in next activity adapter class

```js
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.deleteAddToCartItem(addToCartItemses.get(position).getId());
                addToCartItemses.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Why my queries are not running.

Comment: What method of firebase auth are you using ?

Comment: I am using createUserWithEmailAndPassword and also storing data but i can't use e-mail id as id it is giving me error .

Comment: What should i use for unique id

Comment: All you need to do is retrieve pre assigned uid by firebase just like I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't have to specially** use anything for user unique id as **every logged in user is assigned a unique id** and you can retrieve it like this :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

This code snippet can be found in official firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Do let me know if this info helps you.

Comment: Is authentication failing each time ?

Comment: Use On Completion listener to catch setValue exception of database to see exactly why data is not being saved otherwise. If you successfully authenticate user you can retrieve**unique id** as described in answer

Comment: This was solved. I forgot to to set rules. But what if I want to get id of particular user when he login

Comment: You mean other than the user who is logged in ?

Comment: For same user. If i login then i need my uid to update data

Comment: You will have to retrieve it first like the way described in answer and then manually write it under different node.